# Redirect special PHP files to Subdomains

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have many articles in *foo.com/articles/*

like this:

```
foo.com/articles/banana.php
foo.com/articles/strawberry.php
```

and want redirect SEO to subdirectory like this:

```
banana.foo.com
strawberry.foo.com
```

**EDIT**

when I type (banana.foo.com) show me (foo.com/articles/banana.php).

just show and not realy redirect

I can not create many subdomain by Cpanel, therefore (banana.foo.com) do not create by Cpanel

Comment: This might be what you are looking for: http://serverfault.com/questions/203780/troubleshooting-a-htaccess-wildcard-subdomain-rewrite/203804#203804

Comment: @Joshua Kaiser thx I working in your this post

Answer (score 3):

put this in your .htaccess file ( don't forget to replace "yourdomain" with your domain name)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*).yourdomain.com$
RewriteRule (.*) yourdomain.com/articles/%1.php [L]
```

Now when you request

```
banana.foo.com
```

The result will come from

```
foo.com/articles/banana.php
```

and so on

Comment: 1. I can create subdomain in cpanel for each articles, you think it will work? 2. need Rewrite on? can you write complete code? plz

Comment: @Sinac there is no need to create sub domain for each article, actully the code above will restrict you from having sub domains. and yes ofcourse RewriteEngine should be turned on to taking effect. i have update the code above with complete one, add it to your .htaccess

Comment: thank but it's not show articles/banana.php , can you review your code, may be write a section wrong. thx

Comment: I have make some google search, i got the idea is that you have to point all subdomain to your domain with dns manger in your control panel or by httpd.conf if can access it, however find both in following link, make wildcard to make all subdomains point to your main domain. http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/server/apache/mod-rewrite/subdomains.html

Answer (score 1):

In .htaccess you can do this with the following:

```
RewriteRule ^foo.com/articles/([a-z0-9-]+).php $1.foo.com [PT,L]
```

You'll need mod rewrite installed, and you'll need a wild card subdomain set up in your DNS server.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record

Comment: That is complete code.  It would go into your .htaccess file.  The wild card subdomain is achieved by using an asterisk in your a record where you have your DNS set up. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record

Answer (score 1):

You might do something like:

```
if (preg_match('#.*/articles/([a-z0-9\-_]+)\.php#i', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], $match)) {
    header('Location: http://' . $match[1] . '.foo.com');
    exit;
}
```

Remember to paste this code before any other output or you'll get an error.

Or via `.htaccess` with `mod_rewrite` enabled and `RewriteEngine ON`:

```
RewriteRule ^.*/articles/([a-z0-9\-_]+)\.php$ http://$1.foo.com [R,L]
```

**EDIT**

The reverse would be something like:

```
if (preg_match('#^http://([a-z0-9\-_]+)\.foo\.com.*$#i', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $match)) {
    header('Location: http://foo.com/articles/' . $match[1] . '.php');
    exit;
}
```

And with `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9\-_]+).foo.com$
RewriteRule .* http://foo.com/articles/%1.php [R,L]
```

Comment: it's fail url: foo.com/articles/banana.php.foo.com

Comment: Yes, it's work and redirect directory to subdomain but I want when call subdomain show diretory.

Comment: I test EDIT and add RewriteEngine On RewriteBase / but not work